# How to use a redirected url as the source for <img>, <audio> or <video>?

Tags: node.js, html, reactjs, express, react-router

I have some media files hosted on AWS S3. I want to set up a redirect from my own website to the files, and use the url link from my own website as `src` for the media player, so that I can better track the number of requests for the files from my own site.

In other words, instead of using

```
<audio style="width: 100%;" controls="controls">
<source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/audiofile.mp3“ />
</audio>
```

I want to use

```
<audio style="width: 100%;" controls="controls">
<source src="https://my_own_website.com/tracks/audiofile.mp3“ />
</audio>
```

and have it point to `https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/audiofile.mp3` and play the file.

What I have tried:

1. Redirect on my front end (using react and react-router). I tried setting up a redirect route like so:

   ```
   <Route exact={true} path="/tracks/:id" component={(props) => {
       const id = props.match.params.id;
       window.location.replace(`https://s3.amazonaws.com/soundwiseinc/soundcasts/${id}`);
   }} />
   ```
2. Redirect on my back end (using node.js and express). I tried to redirect like the following:

   app.get('/tracks/:id', (request, response) => {
     const path = String(request.path).slice(8);
     console.log('path: ', path);
     response.redirect(200, `https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/${path}`);
   });

But neither of them worked. The mp3 wouldn't play. And the console error says the source is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a server side page for ex: playmedia.php & pass the cloud file name to that page.
2. Add your tracking code in the page & save analytics data to database.
3. Stream MP3 from S3 using [Amazon S3 Stream Wrapper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-s3-stream-wrapper.html) from playmedia.php

Comment: You can do the same using AWS JS Library.

Comment: This suggestion doesn't really cut it. Because when users play the media files using their own media player, they are not visiting my site. Putting a tracking code on my page wouldn't capture that.